# How can I download a video from an M3U8 file?

Tags: video

I have an [M3U8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U#M3U8) file saved locally.

How can I download the video from this file?

Answer (score 10):

The movie can be easily downloaded using the [FFmpeg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U#M3U8) command line tool:

```
ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,http,https,tcp,tls,crypto -i my_movie.m3u8 -c copy my_movie.ts
```

Note that if the .m3u8 file was downloaded from the Internet and contains relative URLs, those URLs will need to be converted to absolute URLs. For example, `seg-1-v1-a1.ts` → `http://videosource.site/seg-1-v1-a1.ts`. Since .m3u8 is a textual format, one option would be to find/replace those values, either from the command line or a text editor.

Comment: You can actually use the Internet URL to the M3U8 file as the input: `ffmpeg -i "http://videosource.site/video.m3u8" output.ts`. FFMpeg will automatically work out the URLs for each individual file and download them.

Comment: You forgot to include instructions on how to convert the created .ts file into a playable video, i.e.

> ffmpeg -i input.ts -map 0 -c copy output.mkv

Comment: What should I do if ffmpeg throws me the following error: "error reading header ... Not yet implemented in FFmpeg, patches welcome" ? @M. Justin

Comment: @jeppoo1 I'd say, make sure you have the latest FFmpeg, and if it still fails, file a bug report per https://ffmpeg.org/bugreports.html.

Comment: @RaleighL. "You forgot to include instructions on how to convert the created .ts file into a playable video" — I wouldn't say "forgot", since the goal here was to download a full offline copy of the video, not to change the format of the video to something more easily playable locally.